# Django admin getting 400 while trying to upload multiple files from admin panel

Tags: python, django

I am trying to upload images from .zip archive and data that relates for them from .xlsx.

Here is admin.py file where I am trying to import images

```
@admin.register(ImageModel)

class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = "entities/images_changelist.html"
    list_display = ('name', 'img')
    @staticmethod
    def img(obj):
        return mark_safe(
            f'<img src="{obj.image.url}" height="100">') if obj.image else None

def get_urls(self):
    urls = super().get_urls()
    my_urls = [
        path('import-images/', self.import_images),
    ]
    return my_urls + urls

def import_images(self, request):
    form = forms.ImagesUploadForm()
    if request.method == "POST":

         ...Parsing them...
         self.message_user(request, "Your images have been imported")
         return redirect('/admin/images/imagemodel/')

    return render(request, "admin/images_form.html", {"form": form})
```

Here is html of form:
{% extends 'admin/base.html' %}

```
{% block content %}
    <div>
        <form action="." method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit">Import images</button>

        </form>
    </div> 
    {% endblock %}
```

Here is my form:

```
class ImagesUploadForm(forms.Form):
    excel_file = forms.FileField()
    zip_file = forms.FileField()
```

It works good on my local machine but I am getting 400 error on my dev server. Also when I'm adding `if form.is_valid():` I always get `False` and `form.errors == ''`

Comment: Could you be hitting a max filesize limit on your dev server?

Comment: @Alasdair I set it to 20M, but max size of my files are 3M